# Select with ngOptions returns undefined to ngModel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

So I'm trying to use a select field with ngOptions to fill it. But whenever I select something the variable I'm using in ngModel gets turned undefined.

Here's my HTML:

```
<select ng-options="name as operator.name for operator in vm.operators track by operator.value" ng-model="vm.oper"></select>
```

And my Typescript:

```
private operators: Array<any> = [
        {
            name: 'greater than',
            value: '>'
        },
        {
            name: 'less than',
            value: '<'
        },
        {
            name: 'equal',
            value: '='
        },
        {
            name: 'greater than or equal',
            value: '>='
        },
        {
            name: 'less than or equal',
            value: '<='
        }
    ];

    private oper: any = null;
```

The select field is displaying fine, and the values seem to be correct in the HTML. But when I select any value there "oper" becomes undefined

I don't see what is causing this, it should be simple right?

Comment: try to define the value, and remove the trackBy: ng-options="operator.value as operator.name for operator in vm.operators"

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo seems like I had to replace "name as" by "operator.value as" thanks for the comment! I had misunderstood the documentation for ngOptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `operator` instead of `name` or `operator.value`

```
<select ng-options="operator.value as operator.name for operator in vm.operators track by operator.value" ng-model="vm.oper"></select>
```

or

```
<select ng-options="operator as operator.name for operator in vm.operators track by operator.value" ng-model="vm.oper"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialise your `vm.oper` to `vm.operators[0]`? I reckon your `vm.oper` is null so when your `<select>` trying to update `ngModel`, it actually update its scope ngModel not the parent scope

Answer (score 0):

As @JoazitoPolo suggested I had to replace my options string by "operator.value as operator.name for operator in vm.operators" since "name" was undefined it was returning undefined every time. So the part before the "as" is what is actually inserted into the value field of select, I thought that's what "track by" was for. I completely misread the documentation for ngOptions :)